# How can I keep poop from getting caught in my cats fur?

Tags: cats, grooming, defecation

My cat has a terrible problem with poop getting caught in her fur. I have tried to help her clean it but she scratched my arms up terribly. I have another Persian cat who has never had this problem. How can I keep it from happening?

Comment: Is your cat overweight? Because that can make it difficult for her to clean herself.

Answer (score 2):

We see this quite a bit with our over-weight or senior cats (arthritis), easy way to keep it tidy is to give her bum a nice shave. By the sounds of it you will need some assistance. Some options:

1) Your vet clinic can do the bum trim, usually it's a technician that does it - it will be practical but may not look the nicest.

2) Cat Groomer - will be practical and look nice.

If she's feisty with the groomer than your vet clinic is the best option, they are trained to handle fractious cats and get the job done.

If poop is getting stuck because it's diarrhea, that will need a workup.